# Connect three HC-05 Masters to three HC-05 slaves

Tags: microcontroller, uart, embedded, communication, bluetooth

I have 3 Bluetooth modules HC-05 connected to my laptop using an USB-TTL interface and 3 microcontrollers each one has its own HC-05 slave. These devices shall send values to my laptop (each slave sends a value to his own master only). In the laptop side, I have a Python script that manages the communication in this way:

1. Open COM1 (Master 1)
2. Send request to the slave
3. The slave sends a response
4. Close COM1 (Master 1)
5. Open COM2 (Master 2)
6. Send request to the slave
7. The slave sends a response
8. Close COM2 (Master 2)
9. Open COM3 (Master 3)
10. Send request to the slave
11. The slave sends a response
12. Close COM3 (Master 3)

To do so, is it possible to set different baud rates in order to avoid conflicts between them ?

For example:

- Master 1 and Slave 1: 115200 bit/s
- Master 2 and Slave 2: 19200  bit/s
- Master 3 and Slave 3: 9600  bit/s

Is there another efficient way to make sure that every pair of HC-05 avoid other HC-05 devices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind master 1 to slave 1, master 2 to slave 2, and master 3 to slave 3, then the 3 master/slave pairs should communicate without any conflicts and you will not need to keep closing and reopening COM ports. The binding procedure is described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXXAcFOTnBo) - you need CMODE=0.